# Pyplot in iPython: How to continue plotting points inline after exiting a plotting function?

Tags: matplotlib

Suppose I had a function plot() that returned a PathCollection instance:

```
def plot():
    fig = pyplot.scatter(1,2)
    .... # plot other stuff here
    return fig

figure = plot()
```

This could, in an iPython notebook, be displayed inline (right below the code cell).
I want to call something like

```
figure.plot(1,2)
```

to plot a new point (1,2) on that same inline graph, but I can't seem to get this to work. After plotting within a function plot(), how could one continue plotting points on the same plot after exiting plot()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You even don't need the return value `fig`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(x, y):
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    # plot other stuff here

plot(1, 2)
plot(4, 2)
plot(2, 3)
plot(1, 5)

plt.show()
```

Then you got:

[image]